# How to do clean up in native heap when opengl context lost in GLSurfaceview in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm making a wrapper for a native 3d engine.
and I used GLSurfaceView to establish egl context for my engine.

The problem is that, when GLSurfaceView lose its egl context (onPause, etc)， I really wanna free the memory the engine used. However, there seems no way to do it safely.

I've try to override function onPause in GLSurfaceView like below:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
Engine.release();
super.onPause();
}
```

However, it will cause memory problem.

`04-06 21:33:40.415: E/libEGL(8249): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`
`04-06 21:33:40.425: A/libc(8249): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)`

It might due to the memory is freed but the renderer thread is still running.

I think the best way to do clean up is to free memory in renderer thread just before it ends. But I don't know how to implements it.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GLSurfaceView` does its own EGL context management.  It takes all responsibility for creating it, destroying it, and ensuring that it's current on the renderer thread when `onDrawFrame()` is called.

If this is not what you want, you should use a plain `SurfaceView` instead, and issue the various EGL calls yourself.